# Hive 'limit' in subquery executes after full query

Tags: hadoop, hive

I’m testing a rather taxing `rlike` function in a hive query. I figured I’d test against a subset first before applying it to my TB+ of data. The **full** query is:

```
create table proxy_parsed_clean as
select
  a.*,
  case 
    when domainname rlike '.*:443$' then 1
    else 0
  end as used_https
from proxy_parsed a;
```

Since there's so much data, I wrote a query that (ostensibly) would operate against a subset:

```
select
  case 
    when a.domainname rlike '.*:443$' then 1
    else 0
  end as used_https
from (select domainname from proxy_parsed limit 10) a;
```

However, this seems to take *just* as long as the first query. Rather than applying the outer query to the subset, it seems to apply the case statement to the entire dataset and *then* limit. Running an `explain` confirmed my suspicions (**notice the `limit` clause is moved to the end of the query**):

```
> explain select case when a.domainname rlike '.*:443$' then 1 else 0 end from (select domainname from proxy_parsed limit 10) a;

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--+
|                                                       Explain                                                       |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--+
| STAGE DEPENDENCIES:                                                                                                 |
|   Stage-1 is a root stage                                                                                           |
|   Stage-0 depends on stages: Stage-1                                                                                |
|                                                                                                                     |
| STAGE PLANS:                                                                                                        |
|   Stage: Stage-1                                                                                                    |
|     Map Reduce                                                                                                      |
|       Map Operator Tree:                                                                                            |
|           TableScan                                                                                                 |
|             alias: proxy_parsed                                                                                     |
|             Statistics: Num rows: 157462377267 Data size: 6298495090688 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE    |
|             Select Operator                                                                                         |
|               expressions: domainname (type: varchar(40))                                                           |
|               outputColumnNames: _col0                                                                              |
|               Statistics: Num rows: 157462377267 Data size: 6298495090688 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE  |
|               Limit                                                                                                 |
|                 Number of rows: 10                                                                                  |
|                 Statistics: Num rows: 10 Data size: 400 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE                    |
|                 Reduce Output Operator                                                                              |
|                   sort order:                                                                                       |
|                   Statistics: Num rows: 10 Data size: 400 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE                  |
|                   TopN Hash Memory Usage: 0.1                                                                       |
|                   value expressions: _col0 (type: varchar(40))                                                      |
|       Reduce Operator Tree:                                                                                         |
|         Select Operator                                                                                             |
|           expressions: VALUE._col0 (type: varchar(40))                                                              |
|           outputColumnNames: _col0                                                                                  |
|           Statistics: Num rows: 10 Data size: 400 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE                          |
|           Limit                                                                                                     |
|             Number of rows: 10                                                                                      |
|             Statistics: Num rows: 10 Data size: 400 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE                        |
|             Select Operator                                                                                         |
|               expressions: CASE WHEN ((_col0 rlike '.*:443$')) THEN (1) ELSE (0) END (type: int)                    |
|               outputColumnNames: _col0                                                                              |
|               Statistics: Num rows: 10 Data size: 400 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE                      |
|               File Output Operator                                                                                  |
|                 compressed: false                                                                                   |
|                 Statistics: Num rows: 10 Data size: 400 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE                    |
|                 table:                                                                                              |
|                     input format: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat                                          |
|                     output format: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat                       |
|                     serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe                                       |
|                                                                                                                     |
|   Stage: Stage-0                                                                                                    |
|     Fetch Operator                                                                                                  |
|       limit: -1                                                                                                     |
|       Processor Tree:                                                                                               |
|         ListSink                                                                                                    |
|                                                                                                                     |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--+
```

If I am simply to run `select * from proxy_parsed limit 10;`, the query executes blazingly quickly. Can someone explain **A)**, why the query is not executing on the subset, and **B)** how to *make* it do so?

I could just create a temp table, select 10 records into it and then execute the query, but that seems sloppy. Plus, I'd have a temp table to clean up after that. This behavior seems like a Hive bug, i.e., the `limit` behavior is clearly not behaving as it seems it should be in this case.

Comment: Not really an answer, but perhaps this is related to the limit statement not giving any guarantees on which records it will return?

Comment: That was my curiosity as well... but generally in subqueries, the outer query will operate on the (nested) selected content, so it would make sense (intuitively, at least) that the inner select would just return 10 random rows on which the outer query would operate. At least, that's what I thought... can't seem to find any explanation

Comment: I am not sure that your `select *` example generates a proper MapReduce job -- Hive can just use the list of data files and run a pseudo-mapper in "local mode". So you are comparing apples to elephants...

Comment: By the way, how do you store your data? Partitioning would be the first step to explicitly split your dataset into "manageable" chunks. Then a columnar format (such as ORC and Parquet) would reduce the I/O required by queries that apply very selective WHERE filters, and/or fetch only a few columns *(although that's not the case for your query since you fetch all rows and all columns, plus 1)*

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter it's absolutely kicking off a MR job; the `case` statement is the reason for this, not the `select *` (which is why I eliminated the `select *` from the "small" subquery test altogether). But that's not the issue; I was curious as to why it was not operating against the `limit 10` subset, but rather the entire dataset (Note that the second query has a nested `limit` statement).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `limit` is not applied after the `case`, but before and during processing the `case` - it actually gets applied twice. Although it is a coincidence, in this case the two applications of limit correspond to the inner and the outer query, respectively.

In the query plan you can see that the Map phase just selects a single column ("`expressions: domainname`") and also reduces the number of results to 10 (from 157462377267). This corresponds to the inner query. Then the Reduce phase applies the case ("`expressions: CASE WHEN ((_col0 rlike '.*:443$')) THEN (1) ELSE (0) END`") and also reduces the number of rows to 10, but you can see that the expected number of input rows is already 10 in this phase. The Reduce phase corresponds to the outer query.

The reason why the limit is applied twice is the distributed execution. Since at the end of the Map phase you want to minimize the amount of data sent to the Reducers, it makes sense to apply the limit here. After the limit is reached, the Mapper won't process any more of the input. This is not enough however, since potentially each Mapper may produce up to 10 results, adding up to ten times the number of Mappers, thereby the Reduce phase has to apply the limit again. Because of this mechanism, in general you should apply the limit directly instead of creating a subquery for this sole purpose.

To summarize, in my interpretation the query plan looks good - the `limit` is processed in the places where it should. This answers your question about why the `limit` gets applied before the `case`. Sadly, it does not explain why it takes so much time though.

Update: Please see [ozw1z5rd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39400585/5613485) about why this query is slow in spite of using `limit`. It explains that using a subquery causes a MapReduce job to be launched, while a direct query avoids that.

Answer (score 3):

Please look these examples:

```
hive> select case when d rlike '.*:443$' then 1 else 0 end as https from ( select d from domainname limit 5 ) a; 
Query ID = hduser_20160908161152_e0be6db7-f5ac-40ee-b7fb-50ad58ca7f2f
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
:
.
OK
0
0
1
1
0
Time taken: 28.263 seconds, Fetched: 5 row(s)
```

28 Seconds to complete and a map reduce job has been started.

```
hive> select case when d rlike '.*:443$' then 1 else 0 end as https from domainname limit 5; 
OK
0
0
1
1
0
Time taken: 0.162 seconds, Fetched: 5 row(s)
```

0.162 seconds and no map reduce job has been started.

Once you put in into a subquery, a map reduce job is started to select the rows you need.

In mapReduce the input file is splitted and for each split a mapper is started. Each mapper just takes the data and make a transformation on it before to pass it to the combiner, then the partitioner and then the reducer.
Since each mapper works by its own it has no way to know how many rows has been processed. This force a table scan unless you use partitioned / bucketed tables or a temporary table.
As you can see the limit is done after the table scan in your plan:

```
From Map Operator Tree:
1st does a full table scan ( Statistics: Num rows: 157462377267 ) 
2nd the operator limit will take only the first 10 rows.
Reducers will get these only these 10 rows from the Mappers as you can see from the reduce operator tree ( Statistics: Num rows: 10  )
```

this works slow

```
select
  case 
    when a.domainname rlike '.*:443$' then 1
    else 0
  end as used_https
from (select domainname from proxy_parsed limit 10) a;
```

this works fast

```
select
  case 
    when domainname rlike '.*:443$' then 1
    else 0
  end as used_https
from proxy_parsed limit 10;
```

Be aware also limit returns random columns: [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select#LanguageManualSelect-LIMITClause).